# Can a pure function return a promise that resolves after a random amount of time?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I know this example is quite contrived but I am still curious wether or not this can be considered a pure function:

```
const addAsync = (x, y) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
        () => resolve(x + y),
        Math.random() * 1000
    );
});
```

Every call to this function returns a Promise that resolves to the sum of the two arguments. The promise resolves after a random amount of time between 0 and 1 seconds.

For all intends and purposes, this seems to be perfectly pure, meaning that I can treat this function in tests or in my code as a pure function  `(a, b) -> Promise(a + b)`. However, since we are using `Math.random()`, we cannot transform this function into a lookup table and back without losing functionality (we lose the delay). So can this considered to be pure or not?

Comment: How about just providing duration via arguments instead of calculating it inside the function. Of course it will lose randomness but function will become pure. I think the randomness or duration should not be the concern of the function.

Comment: @isa424 Sure I agree, this is not good code and I am not trying to actually use this function. This example is purposely contrived to raise the question of whether or not something like a randomly delayed resolve can be considered pure or not.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it can be consider as a pure function. A pure function is defined as a function where the return value is only determined by its input values, without observable side effects.

In this case the output is only determined by its input and it doesn't produce any side effects. The fact that it takes different amount of time to compute the result should not have an effect on its pureness.

But i would warn that i am not a functional programming expert and i may be wrong

Comment: `Math.random()` is an iterator. `addAsync()` has the side-effect of stepping the iterator.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts while `Math.random()` adds a side effect i would argue that it is not an observable side effect.

Answer (score 3):

Let's clarify the term pure first. Purity means referential transparency, ie. one can replace an expression with its evaluated result without altering the behavior of the program. Here is an action that returns a promise. To visualize the computation I perform logging as a side effect:

```js
const addAsync = (x, y) => new Promise((r, e) => {
    setTimeout(
        z => (console.log(z), r(z)),
        Math.random() * 1000,
        x + y
    );
});

console.log("before");
addAsync(2, 3);
console.log("after");

// logs
"before"
"after"
5
```

Next I substitute the expression`addAsync(2, 3)` with its result, which is a fulfilled `Promise` containing `5`. Since there is no `Promise` literal in Javascript, I represent an already settled promise with `Promise.resolve`:

```js
console.log("before");
Promise.resolve(console.log(5), 5);
console.log("after");

// logs
"before"
5
"after"
```

Looking at the code there seems to be no difference. The expression `addAsync(2, 3)` yields a settled promise (kind of like `Promise(5)`). 
 `Promise.resolve(console.log(5), 5)` on the other hand represents this very settled promise. But by observing the `console.log` side effects we can see that the evaluation order has changed, that is a function that returns a promise actually alters the behavior of a program. Hence such a function is impure.

Comment: I don't agree with your substitution. You replace `addAsync(2, 3)` with the value `5`. However `addAsync(2,3)` does not return `5` it returns a promise, so should you not replace it with this instead: `(new Promise((r) => r(5)).then(console.log)` ?

Comment: ... but its guaranteed to be resolved lazily. So the Promise will always be in a pending state when being returned.

Comment: @basilikum Yes, you're right, but you need to evaluate the chained `then` method as well. I am actually not quite sure how to represent a resolved promise in this case. I think `new Promise((res, rej) => res(console.log(5)))` comes closest.

Comment: @JonasW. A Javascript `Promise` constructor is eagerly executed. You are referring to the deferred `Promise` resolution process, which takes place at the end of the current event loop iteration.

Comment: @ftor As far as I understand it, the goal is to replace `addAsync(2, 3)` with a static value, to replace the function with a lookup table. `addAsync(2, 3)` returns a promise that resolves to `5`. This means it can be replaced with `new Promise(r => r(5))`. So if you just do this replacement, then your two examples would actually log the lines in the exact same order. But I agree that there is a case where executional order is not guaranteed anymore, for example if you involve another asynchronous function.

Comment: @ftor I think you have to substitute the result of the function `addAsync`. The part `.then(x => console.log(x))` is not part of the function and therefore does not need to be substituted. I just still don't know what this actually says about its purity. For example: Does the order in which we log really matter?

Comment: @basilikum Sorry for reaching out to you again, but I think I got it and this is  probably what you've meant in your comments: If we consider the `Promise` constructor all by itself it has the capability to be pure. But `Promise`s are only useful if you chain them and this chaining alters the interpretation order of your program. Since the term _behavior_ includes both the _what_ and the _when_, the `Promise` type can be considered impure.

Answer (score 1):

No.

I would argue that the state the returned Promise is in, is unknown to us, just like the [life of the cat of Schroedinger](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat).   The Promise is either resolved or rejected or pending, but we cannot predict when it is in what state. A snippet that outlines this:

```
 let a = 0;
 addAsync(1,2).then(res => a += res).then(console.log);
 addAsync(0, 1).then(res => a += res).then(console.log);
```

If addAsync would be pure, it would always log the same.

Comment: Interesting example. However, I would argue that the problem here is not that `addAsync` is impure but that `res => a += res` is impure and causing a side effect.

Comment: @basilikum hmmm. I partially agree cause that would also apply to `.then(() => console.log("first"))`. Weve got no global state than but the output would still differ.

Comment: Would it be then safe to say that all asynchronous functions are impure because we cannot guarantee the order of execution?

Comment: @basilikum IMO yes. But i actually hate such meaning definitions. Every meaning has irs scope, one could say that *pure functions* were defined for a functional and sync language and the principles cannot be applied here.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess a more general question is whether or not purity is also determined by "how" and "when" something is returned or just by "what" is returned. But I most real-life examples, returning an async promise most likely means that you do some kind of IO and therefore automatically have an impure function. So maybe it is anyway a meaningless example that, as you said, only really exists outside of the scope of functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is NO. But I offer a simple way to push the impurity elsewhere

In the pure part of your code

```
const incRandomDelay = addAsync.bind(null,1)
```

Now somewhere in the effects part of your code

```
incRandomDelay(10).then( sum => writeToFile(sum) )
```